# AWS DocumentDB errors after migration from mongoDB

Tags: aws-documentdb-mongoapi, aws-documentdb

My application is shifted from MongoDB to DocumentDB. I get these errors after migration though I resolved the connectivity issue to AWS DocumentDB.

```
MongoError: namespace name generated from index name is too long
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:581:63
    at authenticateStragglers (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:504:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:540:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:310:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:453:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:601:20)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'namespace name generated from index name is too long',

{ MongoError: system collection creation not supported
    at Function.create (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:43:12)
    at db.s.topology.insert (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:329:54)
    at handler (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1197:22)
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
  index: 0,
  code: 73,
  errmsg: 'system collection creation not supported',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
ensuring Indexing
```

Comment: The error messages look straightforward: these are differences in DocumentDB's emulation of MongoDB. DocumentDB is a different implementation from the MongoDB server, so variations in behaviour or limits should be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are hitting into the index name limit in DocumentDB. Try creating a shorter index if possible. Refer to this documentation to understand DocumentDB limits better:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits.naming

Answer (score 2):

Infact to our surprise, while
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits.naming

mentions that the "Index Name" contraint can only allow `Length is [3–63] characters.` the confusion is in the name of the constraint.
The term "Index Name" is actually <collection_name>$<index_name>.

So, ultimately you are left with `63 - length of collection_name - 1 (for $ symbol)`

While we have reported this to AWS, we used `name` attribute provided by mongo to set `name` of the index explicitly to proceed further.

Infact, according to "Mongo 4.0 Index Key Limit" document, Mongo allows index name upto 128 characters
Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit

Comment: Is it that the limit is truly 47, or that the index name length calculation includes the collection name?  My understanding (which is admittedly limited) is that (if you'll pardon the Pythonesque interpolation) the length of `{collection_name}${index_name}` must be in the 3-63 character range.

Comment: @C.MichaelPilato Looks like AWS updated their documentation to be more specific.
2.5 years ago when I had faced this issue, their documentation didn't mentioned Index name constraint actually means <collection_name>$<index_name>.
I have updated my answer.